# Umbraco not always showing latest content

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

About a month ago we upgraded from Umbraco 7.4.3 to Umbraco 7.6.5. Since then we've been experiencing problems updating page content. When the person editing the content hits publish sometimes the new content will appear, other times it loads a previous version. There doesn't appear to be any consistency, the same page will show one lot of content on one page load and the other on the next. When we look at the content via the backend then it shows the correct content.

Has anyone else encountered an issue like this and most importantly found a fix?

Thanks

Comment: Could the problem come from cached content? Have you tried loading content from a new client (or a client in private navigation)? Do you have a reverse proxy for cache managment?

Comment: I wondered about it being cached but I tried clearing the browser cache and republishing the entire site. Also seems to switch back and forth, if it were purely a caching issue I would expect to be more consistent.

Comment: To be sure, look at your network tab on your dev tab when loading the content, it's cached if it says cached or the http code of the response is 304.

Comment: Good idea. Of course, now I'm looking for the problem it's behaving itself but I'm sure it's just a matter of time.

Comment: To see the likelihood of cache issue, is your app a big monster running on multiple server?

Comment: It is a bit of a monster on multiple servers but referencing a single database server. However I have recently added Max Pool=1000 to end of the connection string in the web.config and haven't seen the problem since. My best guess is that if the default connection limit of 100 is maxed out it will return cached content instead rather than fall over. But I think it's too early to see if this is definitely the solution. Will monitor it and see how it goes.

Comment: Nicely found! If you have more trouble and haven't already done that try adding: `<add key="umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp" value="true" />` to your `web.config`. It will make sure every server use their own cache witch will limit the possibilities of caches issues.

Comment: Thanks, will keep that one in mind if there are any more issues.